# $\Gamma=SL_2(Z)$ acting on the $\Delta_n$ primitive matrices of determinant $n$. $\Gamma$ acts left transitively on right $\Gamma$ coset.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is related to Lang's Elliptic Functions, Chpt 5, Sec 1.

Denote 2 by 2 matrix $x$'s entries as $a,b,c,d$

$\Delta_n=\{x\in GL_2(Z)\vert det(x)=n,(a,b,c,d)=1\}$ where $n\in Z_{>0}$

"Theorem 1. $\Gamma=SL_2(Z)$ operates left tansitively on right $\Gamma-$coset."

Clearly $\Gamma$ is subset of automorphism of $\Delta_n$ by either left or right action. Consider right coset $\Gamma$\ $\Delta_n$. Then representatives are $\Gamma g$ where $g\in\Delta_n$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ The book says $\Gamma$ acts transitively on the left on the coset $\Gamma$ \ $\Delta_n$. My guess is that book intending to say acting on the right instead as acting on the left say $\Gamma\Gamma g=\Gamma g$ which does not change class at all?